# Windows Phone 8.1 Web Browser launcher LaunchUriAsync Not working

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8.1

I simply want to open the web browser and navigate to a predefined website with a button click. However everything I find has to do with Windows Phone 8 and Silverlight where Microsoft.Phone.Tasks does not work for WP8.1. Perhaps im searching the wrong phrases but I cannot figure out the proper way to do this task.

I should have clarified earlier, I tried using this

```
var uri = new Uri(uriToLaunch);
```

found here [Launcher.LaunchUriAsync](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.system.launcher.launchuriasync.aspx) but VS gives me an error message for using var. I implmented exaclt as MSDN said, however there are still errors.

Comment: what exactly is the compiler error? what is the type of uriToLaunch?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I decided to just use XAML to handle it

```
<HyperlinkButton NavigateUri="http://www.whereever.com"> Go Here </HyperlinkButton>
```

Answer (score 3):

It has been simplified, you just have to write

```
Launcher.LaunchUriAsync(new Uri(url));
```

The Namespace should be Windows.System